# jQuery mobile tabs all tabs closed on load

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using the following code to display tabs

```
<div data-role="tabs" style="padding: 0px;">
<div data-role="navbar" id="filters">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#Cuisine" data-ajax="false">Cuisine</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Course" data-ajax="false">Course</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#search" data-ajax="false">Search</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="Cuisine">
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <label>
                <input type="radio">Southern</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <label>
                <input type="radio">Italian</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <label>
                <input type="radio">Mexican</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Course">
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <label>
                <input type="radio">American</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <label>
                <input type="radio">Mexican</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <label>
                <input type="radio">French</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <label>
                <input type="radio">Cajun & Creole</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <label>
                <input type="radio">Southern</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="search">
    Search
</div>
```

What i need to do to NOT show the first tab. I want all tabs closed.

I've tried:

```
$(function(){

    $('#Cuisine').hide();

})
```

It does not show the first tab content but if i click on the first tab it does not work because his state is active. If i click second tab and then first tab it works.

Thanks,
Radu

Comment: hi can you just make a fiddle so that we can check out the problem

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara already found a solution. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following code will do the job

```
$('#filters').tabs({collapsible: true, active: false})
```